# How do I start loop dynamic line of file

Tags: bash

I have log file like this:

```
...

Tue Nov 18 11:54:59 2014 1 10.8.0.6 148 /home/spy/test/spy.csv b _ i r spy ftp 0 * c
Tue Nov 18 11:55:00 2014 1 10.8.0.6 428 /home/spy/test/spy-atma.csv b _ i r spy ftp 0 * c
Tue Nov 18 11:55:01 2014 1 10.8.0.6 289 /home/spy/test/spy-xfer.csv b _ i r spy ftp 0 * c
Tue Nov 18 11:55:02 2014 1 10.8.0.6 148 /home/spy/test/spy.csv b _ o r spy ftp 0 * c
Tue Nov 18 11:55:03 2014 1 10.8.0.6 428 /home/spy/test/spy-atma.csv b _ o r spy ftp 0 * c
Tue Nov 18 11:55:04 2014 1 10.8.0.6 289 /home/spy/test/spy-xfer.csv b _ o r spy ftp 0 * c
END OF FILE
```

I need to start print last 5 mins interval(from last date) like this:

```
Tue Nov 18 11:55:00 2014 1 10.8.0.6 428 /home/spy/test/spy-atma.csv b _ i r spy ftp 0 * c
Tue Nov 18 11:55:01 2014 1 10.8.0.6 289 /home/spy/test/spy-xfer.csv b _ i r spy ftp 0 * c
Tue Nov 18 11:55:02 2014 1 10.8.0.6 148 /home/spy/test/spy.csv b _ o r spy ftp 0 * c
Tue Nov 18 11:55:03 2014 1 10.8.0.6 428 /home/spy/test/spy-atma.csv b _ o r spy ftp 0 * c
Tue Nov 18 11:55:04 2014 1 10.8.0.6 289 /home/spy/test/spy-xfer.csv b _ o r spy ftp 0 * c
```

I have function for date:

```
entry_time() {
date -d "$(cut -c 1-24 <<< "$1")" +%s
}
```

And I can print start date like this:

```
cutoff=$(( $(entry_time "$(tail -n1 "$LOG")") - $(entry_time "$(tail -n1 "$LOG")") % (5 * 60) ))
```

I can check all lines date is >= cutoff or not, print and going loop for something. But log file is so big and when I check like this, it's working 10-15 hours. Maybe it's work, but I need more simple way. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you just want it from that line once, or something similar to tail -f from that line ?

Comment: I need all lines between last 5 mins interval. If last line 11:55:04, last 5 mins interval mean 11:55:00-11:55:04. I want to print all lines  between 11:55:00-11:55:04. But log files is huge, thats why I don't want to do with line by line control like tail.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand what you want properly then this should work

```
awk '{
        Month=index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",$2)
        Month=(Month+2)/3
        split($4,a,":")
        Time=mktime($5" "Month" "$3" "a[1]" "a[2]" "a[3])
}
(systime()-Time)<300 ' file
```